# Strange input issue with my MacBookPro (people can’t hear me)

Tags: macos, mac, audio, microphone, input

I have a very weird and annoying issue with my Mac (Mac Book Pro 2017 + OS Ventura).

Whenever I have a call, people cannot hear me. They say they can hear the small noises like when I plug in something like my headset, but they can’t hear my voice…

This happens with ALL programmes (Skype, MS Team, etc.) and with ALL devices (built-in microphone, different headsets, etc.). I’ve tried out different options in the Settings (change input source, background noise, volume of the input, etc), but with no result.

I’ve tried a test call with Skype and I can’t hear my voice either.
The sound (output) works perfectly fine.

The problem suddenly appeared during a call and since then, it has never worked again.

Help?

Thank you!

Comment: In System Settings > Sound > Input, does the Input Level meter go up and down as you speak? If you slide the Input Volume slider to the right (more gain/sensitivity) does the Input Level meter show higher sound levels as you speak? Which microphones have you tried, specifically? In your conferencing apps, do you have automatic input level adjustment enabled or disabled?

Comment: Hi Spiff!
Here are my answers:
The Input Level doesn't move when I speak, but it does when I gently tap on my Mac. Either with or without headphones plugged in.
Moving the volume doesn't change the input level meter (still not moving).
I have tried the built-in microphone, and I have tried the microphone on my headphones (which work on phone)
No level adjustment as far as I can see... the issue is the same on Skype, MT Teams, Whatsapp. It happened suddenly during a call...
thanks !